# Split an text into single words, each on a line, with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code, with javascript incorporated in html, in order to split the entered text in the input area into single words, each on a line:

```js
function convertToWords() {

  var MyVar;

  MyVar = document.getElementById("demo");

  console.log(MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "\n"));

  var x = document.getElemenyById("myDiv");

  x.innerHTML = MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "\n");

}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="demo" style="width:100%; height:100px">
</input>

<input type="button" value="Convert to single words" onclick="convertToWords();">
</input>

<br>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

My question, how to let the result be in html for example in a div instead just only as console log?

I tried the highlighted code in the image, but doesnt work :(

Thanks for any help

Comment: replace '\n' with '<br>' ?

Comment: FYI the closing `</input>` tag is unnecessary and can be omitted. If you're dealing with XHTML just add a forward slash to the last bracket of the `input` tag (e.g., `<input type="text" ... />`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 x.innerHTML = MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your function name: `getElementById` instead of `getElemenyById`. Also as everybody else suggest, you can use a `<br>` to put it on a new line.

However look at this solution, it uses more robust coding.

- `\s` as the regex, it splits on all whitespaces. Use this site a nice reference
  http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and https://regex101.com/ to test your regex.
- `split`, it turns the words into an array. So you can do all kinds tricks with it.
- then in the loop, we build block level (`div`) elements (which are by default placed on a new line) and append them to the result div.

```js
//lets improve this: use eventlisteners instead of inline events
document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener("click", convertToWords, false);
//using document.querySelector to select the input button based on its node name and type.
// then add a click event to it that refers to convertToWords.


function convertToWords() {

  var MyVar;

  MyVar = document.getElementById("demo");

  var resultDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); //try to use descriptive names.

  // the use of <br> is not really nice, it works, but this is cleaner
  var wordArray = MyVar.value.split(/\s/); //using \s to split on all white spaces
  wordArray.forEach(function(element){
     //loop over every entry in the array using foreach
     var node = document.createElement("div"); //create a block node element;
     node.textContent = element; //fill div with the text entry.
     resultDiv.appendChild(node); //set node to the result div
  });

}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="demo" style="width:100%; height:100px" />

<input type="button" value="Convert to single words" />

<br>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Functions used that are interesting to get familiar with:

- [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<br>` instead of `\n`

```js
function convertToWords() {

  var MyVar;

  MyVar = document.getElementById("demo");


  var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");

  x.innerHTML = MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "<br/>");

}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="demo" style="width:100%; height:100px">
</input>

<input type="button" value="Convert to single words" onclick="convertToWords();">
</input>

<br>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` instead of `\n` to break line in html.

```js
function convertToWords() {
  var MyVar = document.getElementById("demo");
  //console.log(MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "\n"));
  var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  x.innerHTML = MyVar.value.replace(/ /g, "<br>");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="demo" style="width:100%; height:100px">
<input type="button" value="Convert to single words" onclick="convertToWords();">
<br >
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser doesn't care about `\n`, you can replace the match (a space) with a break.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="output"></div>
```